# Updating PHP 7.4 on Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't update to the latest release

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-7.4

I was just trying to install PHP 7.4 on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04,

Doing a simple `apt install php php-cli` installed the 7.4 version by default,

But when I do `apt update && apt upgrade` the version is still `7.4.3` instead of `7.4.5`!

> > Please note that I'm aware this can be fixed by adding `ppa:ondrej/php` repository.

I'm just trying to understand, if Ubuntu is shipping with 7.4 by default, why doesn't it update to the latest version? will we always get `7.4.3` in Ubuntu **20.04.0** (not the next point release) even after 2-3 years? and the only option is to add the `ondrej/php` repository?

Edit: PHP 7.4.6 has been released few weeks ago, but the version on my server is still stuck on 7.4.3.

Comment: try to use aptitude, it gives you the possibility to study the situation more exactly

Comment: There is always some delay between the latest release and Ubuntu updates. Another possibility is that the mirror you are using is not up to date.

Comment: @e2-e4 I think PHP 7.4.4 was released 2.5 months ago, is it a normal delay? and about the mirror, I haven't changed anything, everything is the default on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.08

Comment: Sounds a bit old indeed. When installing Ubuntu, it determines the best mirror. Try to change it (use 'Software & Updates' / 'Download From'). If the problem is not the mirror, that could be simply that 7.4.4 has some new dependencies that Ubuntu cannot provide at this time. Or that the Ubuntu team doesn't deem necessary to update it at this time (no critical/security bug).

Comment: @e2-e4 Thank you, I changed the mirrors but it's still not updating. Will install GUI later to check you "Download From" method. Mostly I just wanted to understand if this is a temporary thing, or we're stuck with the same version on each point release. reading your comments, it seems to be temporary.

Comment: could you move this to the askubuntu community?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The previously accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62033176/1029261) is wrong.**

This claim

> it's common that some packages remain outdated for a few months

leaves the impression that Ubuntu LTS releases are constantly upgrading to the newest minor version just a few months after the PHP team released them.

**That's not true!**

### Ubuntu's update policy

**TL;DR** Ubuntu's officially packaged PHP is up-to-date security-wise and out-out-date bug-fix-wise.

Here's how Ubuntu / Canonical actually maintains official packages like PHP:

When Ubuntu prepares an LTS release, there's a **feature freeze** ([details](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/ReleaseProcess)) at some point in time. That means even if the packaged software releases a newer minor version (e.g. to fix bugs) before Ubuntu's feature freeze and after the final LTS release, this minor version update isn't going to find it's way into Ubuntu anymore.

In case of Ubuntu Focal Fossa 20.04 LTS, PHP was frozen at version 7.4.3. That means Focal's php package will never again get a minor release update (e.g. 7.4.6) throughout it's support lifespan.

**However, that doesn't mean that Fossa's php package will never ever get updates at all.**

#### SRUs

The contrary is true: it will be patched with these so-called *stable release updates* or short [SRUs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates).

So what goes into SRUs?

Mainly fixes for **high-impact bugs** which boils down to security bugs most of the time. See [SRUs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) for what Ubuntu considers high-impact bugs.

Anyway, what you end up with is Focal Fossa receiving multiple patched versions of PHP 7.4.3 throughout its lifetime. In other words, there exist multiple PHP 7.4.3 versions in Focal Fossa as you can see in the package's [change log](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/p/php7.4/php7.4_7.4.3-4ubuntu2.5/changelog).
It shows multiple versions like `7.4.3-4ubuntu1`, `7.4.3-4ubuntu2`, `7.4.3-4ubuntu2.5` and so on and you can see that mostly security bugs are fixed.

### How to check which version is actually installed?

Problem is that `php -v` will always report `PHP 7.4.3`. However, take a look at the details of the output: `PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2021 15:13:35) ( NTS )`. That it was built Jul 5 2021 already hints that something happened to the seemingly old 7.4.3 version.

To be really sure which version is installed, ask apt: `apt policy php7.4`.

Output:

[image: apt policy output]

In this case `7.4.3-4ubuntu2.5` is installed. Again, take a look at the package's [change log](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/p/php7.4/php7.4_7.4.3-4ubuntu2.5/changelog) to see what's included in that build.

### Are all security bugs affecting PHP 7.4 fixed?

Yes.

Comparing with the [PHP 7.4 ChangeLog](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#PHP_7_4), you'll discover that all security problems (CVEs) except one (afaik just Windows affected) are fixed in the Ubuntu package. Apart from that, just a few non-security bug fixes are included.

Ubuntu's security team is closely [tracking](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam) the CVE database and maintains its own [Ubuntu CVE tracker](https://ubuntu.com/security/cve).

### Should you use Ubuntu's official PHP package?

It depends on your situation. I tend to say it's a good default.

Anyway, here are the facts on which you should base your decision:

When you use Ubuntu's official PHP package, you can be sure that it'll receive security updates throughout the lifespan of the actual Ubuntu release (5 years in case of a LTS version like Focal Fossa 20.04). Even when PHP 7.4 reaches end-of-life (end of 2022), Ubuntu's security team will still patch the official php7.4 package. In other words, even if the PHP team no longer release security fixes, Ubuntu's security team will.

When you're using something like Ondrej's PPA in contrast, you'll have to switch to PHP 8 after end of 2022. If you do not, your PHP will get no more security fixes.

While Ubuntu's php package will get security fixes, it will barely get bug fixes of other sorts. Either you're lucky and your software isn't affected or you'll have to work around those bugs. If a bug seriously affects your software (e.g. performance problem), you may consider switching to a PPA package.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer! I had no idea about these fixes since the version just kept showing 7.4.3... now I can just stick to Ubuntu's official PHP package. Hopefully before the 22.04's feature freeze, PHP 8.1 has received several non-security bug fixes too, and can be used more reliably there.

Answer (score 6):

Kindly use below code to update php 7.4.15

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
  
  sudo apt-get update
  
  sudo apt-get install -y php7.4 php7.4-cli php7.4-common php7.4-fpm

  sudo apt-get install -y php7.4-mysql php7.4-dom php7.4-simplexml php7.4-ssh2 php7.4-xml php7.4-xmlreader php7.4-curl  php7.4-exif  php7.4-ftp php7.4-gd  php7.4-iconv php7.4-imagick php7.4-json  php7.4-mbstring php7.4-posix php7.4-sockets php7.4-tokenizer

  sudo apt-get install -y php7.4-mysqli php7.4-pdo  php7.4-sqlite3 php7.4-ctype php7.4-fileinfo php7.4-zip php7.4-exif

   sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini
   
              Find: cgi.fix_pathinfo  => Remove semi-colon and set 0

              cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
```

Save & quit

php -v

your php version has updated.

Answer (score 5):

[Ubuntu official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/php7.4) shows that the 7.4.3 is the latest available version. So that's not a problem with apt or caching as suggested by @blizzo.

Since we are talking about a LTS release of Ubuntu, it's common that some packages remain outdated for a few months due to stability reasons. (Even patch versions can introduce bugs that make thinks unrealiable, and LTS is meant to be very stable and realiable)

As you wrote on the original question, the best solution is using the `ondrej/php` repository.

Edit:

I asked to ondrej about it and he gently answered with this link: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates that says:

> Once an Ubuntu release has been completed and published, updates for it are only released under certain circumstances, and must follow a special procedure called a "stable release update" or SRU.
>
> ## 2. When
>
> ### 2.1. High-impact bugs
>
> Stable release updates will, in general, only be issued in order to fix high-impact bugs.
>
> ### 2.2. Other safe cases
>
> ...

Comment: Thank you for adding that link, it will be very useful for me in the future.

Comment: @J.Doe, please check the updated answer for a better explanation

Answer (score 1):

Be aware, this can ruin things.  I had been using the PHP 7.4.3 that came with Ubuntu.  My experience adding `ppa:ondrej/php` was not good.

`apt upgrade` first wanted me to install both PHP 7.4 and PHP 8.0.  Then it made PHP 8.0 the default and wanted me to run `apt autoremove` to get rid of the duplicate PHP 7.4 installation.

Restarting Apache caused it to fail with errors and took down all of my websites.

`apt install libapache2-mod-php7.4` was necessary to restore the server, now showing PHP 7.4.16, but all of my websites were throwing server errors indicating none of my PHP extensions were installed anymore.  After reinstalling all of the extensions for PHP 7.4, another Apache restart restored my websites.

`update-alternatives --config php` also helped reset the CLI version back to 7.4.16.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with `apt`. For whatever reason, `apt update && apt upgrade` looks to be pointing to an older release of the software. If it's absolutely necessary, you may indeed need to manually install the latest PHP version via GitHub or some other trusted source.

Answer (score -1):

Found this question and none of the answers worked for me, what worked was:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Adjust `php7.2` to your current module